# cant change color of heading in drupal markup

Tags: drupal-8

```
 $form['bar'] = array(
 '#type' => 'markup',
 '#markup' => '<h1 style="color: red">Example</h1>',
  );
```

This what i've done in my drupal 8 module but it justs display **Example** i didn't see any color change, but the header tag is working, is anything i've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way to add a style attribute is through #attributes variable, which is btw, rarely recommended and (I think) not applicable on an h1 tag.

```
$foo['bar'] = array(
 '#type' => 'container',
 '#attributes' => array('style' => 'padding-left:20px'),
);
```

It may be useful for dynamic background-images, but otherwise, you should always use classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "style" this way. See here : 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.3.x

One workaround will be to gives a class to your H1 tag and then declare the color (or any other attributes) in the CSS.